# View-based NSTableView / NSOutlineView and isGroupItem

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nsoutlineview

I have a View-based NSOutlineView bound to a NSTreeController. Everything seems to work correctly until I implement the  `outlineView:isGroupItem:` method in my delegate, then the group header suddenly stopped showing up. Like this

[image]

I confirmed that If I were to change the NSOutlineView to cell-based then the group item shows up properly. Similar behavior is also observed for NSTableView. Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it!

Turned out I had to implement the following method in the `NSOutlineView` delegate

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView 
     viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                   item:(id)item {
    if ([self outlineView:outlineView isGroupItem:item]) {
        NSString *vId = [[[outlineView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:0] identifier];
        return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:vId owner:self];
    }
    return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
}
```

Apparently, by default view based NSOutlineView generate view for each cell in the table by locating the view with the same identifier as the column. In the case of a group item / group row however, there is no `tableColumm` associated with that row, therefore the view turns out to be nil and not show up.

Playing around with apple's [TableViewPlayground sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010727) really helped! Highly recommended!

**Addendum:** In Interface Builder if you add *Source List* object instead of *Outline View*, it will add two prototype view rows for you.

Allowing you to design different looking header and data rows and referring to them in code by their identifier.

*Header Cell:*
[image: Interface Builder > Header Cell]
*Data Cell:*
[image: Interface Builder > Data Cell]

You can of course also manually add as many prototype view rows as you like.

Comment: Why isn't `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` in the [official `NSOutlineViewDelegate` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: how to remove the grouped header separator lines (lines on top and bottom in groups header)?
  OR 
how can we customize grouped NSOutlineVIew header?